# Hashes of all previous blocks are known but why the hash of block.number-1 is vulnerable and not the remaining 255 blocks?

Tags: blockchain, mining

I have read at different places that blackhash(block.number-1) is vulnerable (to miner's [blockhash(block.number-1) vulnerability](https://medium.com/coinmonks/is-block-blockhash-block-number-1-okay-14a28e40cc4b)) because the hash is available but what about the other previous 255 hashes? For instance why blockhash(block.number-2) is not vulnerable even though it is also available. Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Please share one or more links to these "different places".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you talk about randomness, any previous block is also vulnerable. `blockhash(block.number-1)` is just an example people use for 'previous blockhash'.

Comment: `blockhash(block.number)` returns 0 but I saw people talking about using it as a source of randomness. Do you know why? Can't find the source.

Comment: @Maxareo See 'future block hash' here https://soliditydeveloper.com/2019-06-23-randomness-blockchain/. But essentially you just store the block number and then use it in a second later transaction to receive the hash.